# how do change the state of one switch when user changes another switch in android application

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, kotlin

In my android activity I have 2 switches. I want to link both the switches such that if the user drags switch1 then switch2 should also move, but when switch2 is dragged it should have no effect on switch1.

Kotlin code would be appreciated

Thank you

My XML Code

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rotation="90"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rotation="90"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch1" />
```

Comment: Code would be appreciated. Please show a [mre] of the two switches which do not yet exhibit the desired behaviour.

Comment: i dont know how to start with it. As of now i have simply added 2 switches in android studio

Comment: Yes, show that please. Yoou need to demonstrate what you already have, in order to avoid the "I want" impression.